# RabbitMq message re delivery

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Say I have a connection to rabbit, and I've pulled 1000 messages, but have not yet ack'd them, as they are being processed by a single thread out of a Blocking collection.

Now suppose my connection dies and is auto recovered. At this point all of these msgs on the server will be re queued for delivery. But I still have copies of them locally, with the old Delivery tag.

This leads me to believe I should handle connection or channel down events by clearing my local queue out.

Can you confirm this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is the case. Those messages will be redelivered.

So in addition to clearing our your locally queued messages, you might want to consider your prefetch so that you don't have so many messages queued locally.

Is your strategy is to pull 1000, process them all, then finally ack them all? I can see that due to performance reasons you might do this so you can send a single ack with multiple=true, but it does introduce extra redelivery and duplicate processing risks.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.If you are processing one message at a time you can set prefetch count as 1 and you may not need to clear any messages locally,too.